# Get only images links that missing the alt attribute with preg_match_all in PHP

Tags: php, file-get-contents, preg-match-all

Hello and sorry for my bad english.

I am trying to get all images links from an third party website, but I want to get only the links that's do not have the alt attributes. I want to output the links.

Now I have this code:

```
<?php

$content = file_get_contents('domain.com');

preg_match_all('/<img(.*?)>/is',$content,$page_images);
$total_images = count($page_images[1]);

preg_match_all('/<img(.*?)alt="(.*?)"(.*?)>/is',$content,$alt_images);
$total_alt = count($alt_images[2]);

$missing_alt = $total_images - $total_alt; 


echo $missing_alt.' alt attributes are empty or missing';

?>
```

This code is working and gives the count of total images that are missing the alt attribute.

Now I want to output also the links that are missing the alt="" attribute.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/443341

Comment: So there is not way to do that?

Comment: It is possible, but you should use right tools, regex is not one of them. Look at @Alex's answer.

Answer (score -1):

HTML shouldn't be parsed with regex.

It's much better, safer and easier to do it with [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) or [SimpleHTMLParser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).